# Stateful uniq functionality

Tags: pipe, uniq

I've a program producing large amount of redundant information. I'd like to store only unique lines produced on `stdout`, but I can't do it in multiple steps, like:

`./prog > out
cat out | sort | uniq > out2`

`out` file would be too big. How can I achieve a "stateful uniq" functionality, where the `stateful_uniq` would consume lines and emit only the ones it didn't see before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't `./prog | sort | uniq > out2` do what you want? Or even `./prog | sort -u > out2` if your `sort` supports it...

To see unique lines as they come out without sorting the output, you can use an associative array with `awk`:

```
./prog | awk '!(count[$0]++)'
```

As pointed out by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas), `sort` limits its memory use using temporary files; the `awk` solution doesn't, so if memory use is a concern then it might not be appropriate.

Comment: `sort` has to sort everything first, no? It'll run out of memory.

Comment: Ah right, that's what you meant by "too big"; I thought it was because of the disk space used!

Comment: `sort` limits its memory usage by resorting to temporary files. The `awk` solution stores all unique lines in memory so could end up using more memory than `sort` would.

Comment: If amount of uniqueness is finite, then I would hope that the amount of memory used by sort is proportional to uniqueness (not total input size). Though it would never produce any output until the last bit of input has been read.